# I cant install programs on Ubuntu error subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2

Tags: installation, uninstall

please help, i cant install or unistall programs the error is that:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 192274 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-25-generic
Error in function: 
Setting up linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic (3.5.0-25.39) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of overlayfs
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.5.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of /cow.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.5.0-25-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
sudo update-grub
```

if you get: `failed to get canonical path of /cow`

follow [this procedure](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd/#.US-dUem8z3w)

Comment: i forgot to mention that i run ubuntu from my USB...ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            2,9G  2,1G  653M  77% /
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
 is it ok? becose i run the first and didnt help...

Comment: yep that's fine, my answer is crap. Hold on a sec

Comment: and if there is a way to add more space on my usb boot please tell me.. i have 1GB more to give :)

Comment: yeah it show me the error you said... but that help your are giving me does changes on my computer hard disk. As i said i run ubuntu from my usb... i dont wanna do changes on my hard disk coz there i have install the windows7 and i dont wanna lose something